# data attributes being lost when displaying html using javascript on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have javascript code which loads html content into a div tag. The problem is that few data attributes are not being displayed when this is loaded in Chrome browser. The problem does not happen in Firefox. 
The actual html code is generated by a perl script and written offline into a .html file.

jquery code to load the following html code:

```
$.get("/allshows.html", function(html_string)
   {
      $( "#imgthingy" ).html(html_string);
 },'html');
```

html code:

```
<div class="fade-area-2">
    <a href="Under the Dome" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ShowModal" data-sorting="Under the Dome" data-image="http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/tv/264492/tvthumb/under-the-dome-51cc511a76f1a.jpg" data-NextEpisode="S3E13" data-Genre="Drama | Science-Fiction | Thriller " data-lastaired="S3E13" data-Premiered="2013-06-24" data-Status="Ended" data-TotalSeasons="0" data-summary="&lt;p&gt;&lt;b&gt;Under the Dome&lt;/b&gt; is the story of a small town that is suddenly and inexplicably sealed off from the rest of the world by an enormous transparent dome. The town&#39;s inhabitants must deal with surviving the post-apocalyptic conditions while searching for answers about the dome, where it came from and if and when it will go away.&lt;/p&gt;" class="nocli">
        <img src="http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/tv/264492/tvthumb/under-the-dome-51cc511a76f1a.jpg" class="img-rounded" style="width: 140px; height: 140px; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    </a>
    <a href="Person of Interest" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ShowModal" data-sorting="Person of Interest" data-image="http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/tv/248742/tvthumb/person-of-interest-588d94ea26e7f.jpg" data-NextEpisode="S5E13" data-Genre="Drama | Action | Crime " data-lastaired="S5E13" data-Premiered="2011-09-22" data-Status="Ended" data-TotalSeasons="0" data-summary="&lt;p&gt;You are being watched. The government has a secret system, a machine that spies on you every hour of every day. I know because I built it. I designed the Machine to detect acts of terror but it sees everything. Violent crimes involving ordinary people. People like you. Crimes the government considered &quot;irrelevant&quot;. They wouldn&#39;t act so I decided I would. But I needed a partner. Someone with the skills to intervene. Hunted by the authorities, we work in secret. You&#39;ll never find us. But victim or perpetrator, if your number is up, we&#39;ll find you.&lt;/p&gt;" class="nocli">
        <img src="http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/tv/248742/tvthumb/person-of-interest-588d94ea26e7f.jpg" class="img-rounded" style="width: 140px; height: 140px; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    </a>
</div>
```

Full pastebin of the html file: [htmlfile](https://pastebin.com/7tNSNA6J)

Unfortunately in Chrome, it looks like this:

```
<div class="fade-area-2">
  <a href="Under the Dome" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ShowModal" data-sorting="Under the Dome" data-summary="
    <p>
        <strong>Under the Dome</strong> is the story of a small town that is suddenly and inexplicably sealed off from the rest of the world by an enormous transparent dome. The town's inhabitants must deal with surviving the post-apocalyptic conditions while searching for answers about the dome, where it came from and if and when it will go away.
    </p>" data-image="http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/tv/264492/tvthumb/under-the-dome-51cc511a76f1a.jpg" data-nextepisode="" data-genre="" data-lastaired="" data-premiered="" data-status="" data-totalseasons="" class="nocli">
    <img src="http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/tv/264492/tvthumb/under-the-dome-51cc511a76f1a.jpg" class="img-rounded" style="width: 140px; height: 140px; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
    </a>
     <a href="Person of Interest" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#ShowModal" data-sorting="Person of Interest" data-summary="
    <p>You are being watched. The government has a secret system, a machine that spies on you every hour of every day. I know because I built it. I designed the Machine to detect acts of terror but it sees everything. Violent crimes involving ordinary people. People like you. Crimes the government considered &quot;irrelevant.&quot; They wouldn't act so I decided I would. But I needed a partner. Someone with the skills to intervene. Hunted by the authorities, we work in secret. You'll never find us. But victim or perpetrator, if your number is up, we'll find you.</p>" data-image="http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/tv/248742/tvthumb/person-of-interest-588d94ea26e7f.jpg" data-nextepisode="" data-genre="" data-lastaired="" data-premiered="" data-status="" data-totalseasons="" class="nocli">
    <img src="http://assets.fanart.tv/fanart/tv/248742/tvthumb/person-of-interest-588d94ea26e7f.jpg" class="img-rounded" style="width: 140px; height: 140px; margin-right:10px; margin-bottom:10px;">
  </a>
</div>
```

Full pastebin of the loaded html (via console.log): [html in Chrome](https://pastebin.com/9VPWSfCk)

`data-NextEpisode`, `data-Genre`, `data-lastaired` etc are all lost while displaying in Chrome. Why is this happening? How can I avoid this?

In Firefox:
[image: Firefox-img]

In Chrome:
[image: Chrome-img]

Comment: It looks like it's truncating at the `&gt;`, but also re-ordering the `data-` attributes (hence you lose some).  Can you confirm, via browser debugging, that `html_string` is the value you're expecting after the `$.get` ?

Comment: @freedomn-m Actually, no. When the string is output to console, it is lacking those data attributes on Chrome. Once again, on Firefox, the string is correct, and exactly the same as in the html file.

Comment: Which means the issue is with the `.get()` rather than the `.html()`.   Can you expand the `$.get` out to a full `$.ajax({ type:'GET', url:"/allshows.html" .. `  then you can try specifying `dataType:"html"` or `dataType:"text"`.   No idea why it's happening in Chrome, just trying to find an alternative.

Comment: Can you change the php html output?  `data-` attributes *should* be lowercase and I notice that the ones you're losing are the ones that are not lowercase .

Comment: if you load with `dataType:"text"` then the browser shouldn't parse the html until it's time to apply it (but you might still lose them then)

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you! Changing it to `$.ajax()` fixed it!

Comment: Did you use `dataType:"html"` or `dataType:"text"` in your $.ajax call?

Comment: @freedomn-m It worked with `dataType:"html"` itself